# Is using an embedded alias to define methods on a struct in a different package efficient?

Tags: go, methods, package

Unless my tests are wrong, all other options, including using plain functions take roughly 35% longer than defining methods in a different package using an embedded alias. I've probably done something wrong, and I'd love to know what it is. For complete details see [this repository](https://github.com/emadera52/mvsf).

[EDIT] Thanks for the comments/suggestions. The following shows only code related to comparing "method" to "meth". The former uses typical methods defined in the models package along with the struct. The "meth" option defines methods using an embedded alias defined in the datactrl package. The first code example includes the struct definition and an exported default instance of the struct used in the tests.

**from package models, file models.go**

```
type CmntData struct {
    ID          int
    Slug        string
    Title       string
    PageID      int
    Text        string
    DateCreated time.Time
    CreatedBy   int
}

var DefaultCD = CmntData{ID: 100, Title: "Demo Comment",
Text: "This is a test comment", PageID: 1000, CreatedBy: 4242}


// Local methods called by the "method" test

func (cd *CmntData) NewComment(ncd CmntData) *CmntData {

    ncd.DateCreated = time.Now()

    return &ncd
}

func (cd *CmntData) DefaultComment(cnt int) *CmntData {

    dcd := DefaultCD
    dcd.Slug = "demo-comment-" + strconv.Itoa(cnt + 1)

    return cd.NewComment(dcd)
}
```

**from package datactrl, file comments.go**

```
// Types and method definitions used to add methods to models.CmntData

type roCmntData struct {
    ModelCD models.CmntData
}

type roCD struct{}

// roComment allows us to effectively add methods to models.CmntData.
// Data and "local" methods defined for models.CmntData are accessible.
type roComment struct {
    *roCmntData  // Provides access to models.CmntData
    *roCD        // Required to make the magic happen
}

// Other packages must use Rcd to access methods added to models.CmntData
var Rcd = roComment {
    roCmntData: &roCmntData{},
    roCD: &roCD{},
}

// Remote methods called by the "meth" test

func (cd *roComment) NewComment(ncd models.CmntData) *models.CmntData {

    cd.roCmntData.ModelCD = ncd
    cd.ModelCD.DateCreated = time.Now()

    return &cd.ModelCD
}

func (cd *roComment) DefaultComment(cnt int) *models.CmntData {

    dcd := models.DefaultCD
    dcd.Slug = "demo-comment-" + strconv.Itoa(cnt + 1)

    return cd.NewComment(dcd)
}
```

**from package main, file main.go**

```
if cmd == "method" {
    tstart := time.Now()
    dcd := models.CmntData{}
    for i := 0; i < limit; i++ {
        defCD = dcd.DefaultComment(i)
    }
    tfinish := time.Now()
    elapsed = tfinish.Sub(tstart)
}

if cmd == "meth" {
    tstart := time.Now()

    // datactrl.Rcd provides access to remote models.CmntData methods
    dcd := &datactrl.Rcd 
    for i := 0; i < limit; i++ {
        defCD = dcd.DefaultComment(i)
    }
    tfinish := time.Now()
    elapsed = tfinish.Sub(tstart)
}
```

[Screen shot of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eh4W3.png) taking the average of 40 loops, where each loop returns the average of one million test runs. For the record, both "func" and "function" tests complete within 2ms of the result posted by "method".

Comment: What one is supposed to see from your code? All 4 things run approximately the same time here.

Comment: Can you convert the code to the minimal required to illustrate the issue and share , may be a https://play.golang.org would do

Comment: Have you tried looking at the dissassembly? Also: Your methods take a pointer receiver, the functions take a value argument. The method is passed a pointer, the functions are passed the full object. Unless the compiler optimizes that difference out (which I don't think it does), that would explain the difference in performance

Comment: Don't just link to external resources, and please create a [mcve] to demonstrate the issue. Also, what is an "embedded alias"?

Comment: Unfortunately, because three packages are required to create the test, playground is not an option. I tried to create a gist, but couldn't figure out how to put models and datactrl in sub-directories.  I have modified the question to show the minimum code needed and a screen shot to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @zerkms Please see the screen shot included with the edited question.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Van Oote My understanding is that structs are always passed as a pointer. That said, to create the effect of passing by value, the pointer points to a copy of the struct. That, of course, takes time.

Comment: Note that the results shown compare methods to methods, which eliminates the issue of extra time needed to the struct passed to the functions.

Comment: @JimB The terms alias and embedded in this context come from other stack overflow answers that showed me how to add methods to a struct defined in another package.

Comment: @emadera52: "Aliases" are a specific concept, and the feature is only being added in the upcoming 1.9 release. Structs are _not_ always passed as a pointer, I'm not sure how you could come to that conclusion. Everything is passed by value, be it a struct or a pointer (or a slice, array, map, etc).

Comment: For reference, methods and functions are called in the exact same manner. You can even call a method explicitly as a function via [`method expression`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions). The difference in your two remaining cases is that is that each call in `meth` has 1 alloc, while each call in `method` has 2. You can get a better sense of timing and allocations by using the builtin benchmarking facilities, rather than timing these on your own.

Comment: @JimB Thanks for your comments. I think the last one answers my question as to why **meth** is faster than **method**. The extra alloc required by **method** is the likely culprit.

Comment: @JimB With regard to passing by reference or value, I'm an old fart. A relic from the days when passing by value meant passing on the stack, or better yet, in a register. I accept that in Go terminology there is no such restriction. Times have changed, and for the better I would agree.

Comment: @emadera52 I don't know how/where you got the idea from that structs are always passed via pointers (ie indirection). Especially if the receiver is being passed a pointer to a _copy_. That's extremely wasteful. Nonetheless, I had a quick look at the golang specs and it simply states that _"In a function call, [...], the parameters of the call are passed by value to the function and the called function begins execution. The return parameters of the function are passed by value back to the calling function when the function returns."_

Comment: These values can be anything from a pointer to a full struct. Although I haven't looked into it in a while, but I wouldn't be surprised if golang were to use some static analysis while compiling, and only pass a copy if the caller writes to the struct. That said, the go compiler is -compared to things like the gcc compilers- quite young. It probably doesn't perform the same kind of complex optimisations as a 20+ year old C compiler does

Comment: I also found [this google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/INedfATw74A) Where Rob Pike spells it out quite clearly: _"In Go, everything is passed by value. Everything. "_. That's exactly the same as it would be in C

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem That all makes perfect sense given that a pointer is a value. As you know, in C, the programmer is responsible for deciding when to pass a pointer vs when pass a value. If the choice is pointer, allocating memory and creating the value in memory, as well as releasing the memory are all done implicitly. Go hides some of that complexity, but apparently not as much as I thought. Thanks for your input. So much to learn, so little time.

Answer (score -1):

Actually @JimB answered my question, but it is in a comment regarding the question.

The answer appears to be that typical methods, defined in the same package as the struct they become part of, require an extra memory allocation. What I've referred to as **remote** method definitions get a tiny edge as a result.

Keep in mind that the edge may not be worth doing something that requires a lot of comments to clarify what's going on. On the other hand, if you need/want to separate data manipulation from data definition, **remote** methods will allow you to do that, and you save what amounts to a few microseconds on every call as an added bonus. :)

His suggestion to use Go's Benchmark facility, built in with testing, sounds like a good one. I'll be looking into it myself.

Comment: `methods, defined in the same package as the struct they become part of, require an extra memory allocation` - no that's not the reason for the extra allocation. The "method" test creates a new value every time, while the "meth" test writes a value to the same location pre-allocated in `Rcd` every time. You can test this by looking at the address of the return pointer in each case.

Comment: Interesting. Does that mean that "method" could, in theory, be modified to do the same thing. In practice, the value (to me) of "meth" is in being able to define methods on a struct defined in a different package. I see now that cutting the time by 25% is insignificant because a method call is so fast to begin with. Thanks for taking time to look into the matter.